# How do I hide the OptionMenu in a toolbar from a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-menu, optionmenu

I inflate the option menu in the `HomeActivity`. But i need the option menu to show in some `fragments`, and hide in others.

I tried with `setHasOptionsMenu(false);` line in `onCreate()` fragment method.

This is the `optionmenu` button declaration in `HomeActivity`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //initialize button
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

//action when i press it
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // action with ID action_refresh was selected
        case R.id.toolbar_acquista:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Acquisto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I'm trying to have this in a `fragment` the option menu `clickable` and visible, in others `unclickable` and invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't inflate menu in home activity instead inflate menu inside the fragments

like this

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_sample, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

this way menuitems inflated in the fragments only visible when the fragment is visible

Comment: Thank you, i moved onCreateOptionsMenu in the fragment, and add in onCreate setHasOptionsMenu(true); and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

first `Clear Menu` like

```
@Override 
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
}
```

and then **TRUE** as `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `onCreate()` of fragment method

Answer (score 0):

**First of all Override Create Method in Fragment** and write **setHasOptionsMenu(true)**

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

**Then after override OnPrepareOptionMenu method in Fragment** and Write code which i place inside it.
I hide my Search Menu only. Similarly You can hide all menu item or selective item as per your choice.

```
   @Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    if(item!=null)
        item.setVisible(false);
}
```